# how to transfer in sftp with password ? put command not sending the full file

Tags: unix, sftp, expect

I am new to UNIX. Need help in finding the correct approach to send a file.

I have to send a big file 1gb and the time it takes to sftp manually is approx 10 mins, We have tried the below script because we have to login with password.

The problem here is before completely transferring the file. The script come out of the SFTP connection with no error.

Script:

```
` expect -c " `
    spawn sftp ${remote_user}@${remote_host}
    expect \"password\"                     
    send  ${remote_pswd}\r                  
    expect sftp>                            
    send \" cd ${remote_path}\r \"          
    expect sftp>                            
    send \" lcd ${source_path}\r \"         
    expect sftp>                            
    send \" put ${source_file} \r \"        
    expect sftp>                            
    send \" echo $? \r \"                 
    expect sftp>                              
    send \"bye\" " '                        `
```

Log:

```
` spawn sftp DataStageIM2@192.168.79.15                               
 DataStageIM2@192.168.79.15's password:                               
 Connected to 192.168.79.15.                                          
 sftp>  cd /users/StoreStockManagement/ReferenceData/Inbound          
 sftp>  lcd /staging/oretail/external/data/DSPRD/Output/Pricing/INT340
 sftp>  mput hhtstore_price.dat 
 Uploading hhtstore_price.dat to /users/StoreStockManagement/ReferenceData/Inbound/hhtstore_price.dat  
 hhtstore_price.dat 3%  189MB  18.1MB/s   04:31 ETA+ [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]`
```

--Here after transferring 3% of the file this script comes out and I cannot see the file there. But when i manually trying the sftp it is working. Only with script it is not copying.

Can some one help here

Answer (score 0):

The default timeout value for the `expect` command is 10 seconds. So, after `put`, expect will wait for 10 seconds to see the prompt, then timeout, then continue on with the script.

Clearly you want to wait for however log as necessary to transfer the file, so add this to your script:

```
set timeout -1
```